# I am unsure about how to remove cases from the "select case" statement in visual basic after a certain case has been selected more than 3 times

Tags: vb.net

I've a word guessing game in development. It works so that when the play button is clicked, a random number between 1 and 20 will be generated. This new randomly generated number will then go into the select case statement as shown in the code below:

```
    Dim RND As New Random
      Dim rndNumber As String
    rndNumber = RND.Next(1, 20)
    Dim RndWord as string
    Dim RndHint as string
    select case(rndnumber)
    case 1
    RndWord = "hockey"
    RndHint = "A ball game played with curved, wooden sticks"
    Case 2
    RndWord = "dinghy"
    RndHint = "This is a small boat usually made out of rubber"
```

These are just 2 out of 20 similar cases.

The selected case contains a word and a hint that will be displayed upon that case being selected. My problem is, how do I remove a case after it has been selected three times; removing the word and the hint from the program completely so that they won't appear again. I've looked into different types of arrays; however, after 2 hours of research and many attempts at using them they don't seem to fit this purpose.

Comment: You should provide more code, so we can see the words, the actual things you do in the remainder of the `select case` statement (NB: it's not a function); etc. Probably the `select case` statement is not even the best construct to use for your case. Consider a dictionary/collection/array of words for that purpose.

Comment: Update: I've had the idea that I may not have to remove a case, and instead I could instead remove the numbers that would be randomly generated-problem being I don't know how to do this either.

Comment: I might track the random numbers generated, and how many times each was generated and just keep getting new random numbers until you get one that is not used 3 times. You could use a Dictionary of int, int.

Comment: @Crowcoder I did this 50 times and repeated 3 times i.e. I generated 50 numbers, recorded them and closed the program, then repeated 2 more times. I did it 3*50 rather than 150 for the program ends after the user has guessed 30 words right; my intention is to leave words in but I don't want the case where which some words aren't used; wheras, one word has been used over 7 times. In all three tests there were at least 2 words not used at all. This is why I want after 3 times for the word to disappear. I'm looking into using a dictionary after what trincot above said.

Comment: I can't understand what you just said at all, but if you are trying to track this between restarts of the application then you need a persistent data store like file, database, user settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove your case statement, it makes is less manageable. What if tomorrow you decide to add 5 more questions? You will end up changing the code. You can keep all the data externally and have them read into a dictionary object.

Define these at class level:

```
Dim questions As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()
Dim questionAppearedCount As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)()
```

Create new Sub with this:

```
Public Sub FillQuestions()
   questions.Add(1, New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("hockey", "A ball game played with curved, wooden sticks"))
   questions.Add(2, New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("dinghy", "This is a small boat usually made out of rubber"))
   'Also, you may use File.ReadAllLines() to fill from a file.
End Sub
```

Finally, BtnGenerate_Click

```
Dim rnd As Random = New Random()
Dim rndNumber As Integer = rnd.[Next](1, 20)
If questionAppearedCount.ContainsKey(rndNumber) Then 
   questionAppearedCount(rndNumber) = questionAppearedCount(rndNumber) + 1 
Else 
   questionAppearedCount.Add(rndNumber, 1)
End If
If questionAppearedCount(rndNumber) > 3 Then
   'do not show question, instead get Next random
Else
   return question(rndNumber)
End If
```

Here is the code, so I keep questions in dictionary, show them using dictionary.
In the above code, question can be read from external file using `File.ReadAllLines()`
When question is shown, add to the count and if count is > 3, don't show.

Comment: I do however have multiple problems with this, the first being how do assign the generated word and hint to labels? Secondly, where should this Public Shared Sub go in the program as before, when i was using the cases, they went under the BtnGenerate_click, so that when the button was clicked, the word would be generated. This is a complication for most of my code was under that sub but as this sub contains an End If End Sub method then it cannot go under that sub, leaving me stuck as to where to put it.

Comment: This is just a sample code. You need to split the code and keep the Dictionary objects at global / class level. Have 1 method to fill questions dictionary. Then the code from "Dim rnd" onwards can go in to your BtnGenerate_click event. Since your question didn't mention about the click event i just added some sample Sub. Update my answer.

Comment: I don't think you will ever get number 20 with rnd.Next(1,20)  Next is inclusive of the lower bound and exclusive of the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array to count each case.
If the count is 3 you loop.
If less you increase the counter in the array and exit the loop so it ll use a case statement.
Be carreful in this case if all counters reach 3 the program wil loop infinitively.

Else an array for all the cases data.
When 3 is reached the datas are moved at the end of the array and the max index is decreased by one. At beginning its 20... next 19.. etc...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this code.

My sample also has a list of questions.

A very important differences though:
  It does the filtering of the data BEFORE the random call.  So, it's only searching for the questions that are valid.  In certain cases, repeated random calls very close together might produce the same result, so this verifies you only do it once.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Dim questionAppearedCount As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

    Public  Sub Main()

        Dim questions As Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()
        questions.Add(1, New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("hockey", "A ball game played with curved, wooden sticks"))
        questions.Add(2, New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("dinghy", "This is a small boat usually made out of rubber"))



        questionAppearedCount = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)()
        SelectQuestion(1)
        SelectQuestion(1)
        SelectQuestion(1)

        ' Get the Filtered List
        Dim filteredQuestions() as KeyValuePair(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = questions.Where(Function(ByVal item as KeyValuePair(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))) Not questionAppearedCount.ContainsKey(item.Key) OrElse questionAppearedCount(item.Key) < 3).ToArray()
            Dim rand As New Random
            Console.WriteLine(filteredQuestions(rand.Next(0, filteredQuestions.Count - 1)).Value)


    End Sub

    Public Sub SelectQuestion(ByVal questionNumber as Integer)
        ' Add Question
        If questionAppearedCount.ContainsKey(questionNumber) Then
            questionAppearedCount(questionNumber) += 1
        Else
            questionAppearedCount(questionNumber) = 1
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

And here's some vb.net helper code that you can use to REFACTOR your case statements automatically.  Just paste your code into it and it will return the equivalent code to the console.  You'll replace your code with this code.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Dim questionAppearedCount As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

    Public  Sub Main()

        'Dim questions as New Dictionary(Of Integer, KeyValuePair(Of String, String))

        For rndnumber as Integer = 1 to 20

        Dim RndWord as String = ""
        Dim RndHint as String = ""

        select case(rndnumber)
    case 1
    RndWord = "hockey"
    RndHint = "A ball game played with curved, wooden sticks"
    Case 2
    RndWord = "dinghy"
    RndHint = "This is a small boat usually made out of rubber"
        end SElect

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rndword) Then

            'questions.Add(rndnumber, new KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(rndword, rndhint))
        Console.WriteLine("questions.Add(" & rndnumber & ", new KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(""" & rndword.Replace("""", """""") & """,""" & RndHint.Replace("""", """""") & """))")


        End If


    Next

    End Sub



End Module
```